# Looking for that cool new WYSIWYG inline HTML editor

Tags: jquery, wysiwyg

It's been on HN some time ago, but hours of searching HN and googling later I still haven't found it. It's kinda like NiceEdit Inline mode..

Comment: It had a nice demo site and looked like a product, not something somebody did in his pare time - if this helps.. 
It worked kind of like this: you clicked the text and could edit it right away without the text being replaced by a textbox or something. + a panel for font controller etc popped uo. So as I said kinda like Nicedit's inline mode.

Comment: Some weeks ago on HN. But searching there doesn't bring up anything. Like it's been deleted..

Comment: Can you explain what 'HN' means?

Answer (score 2):

trying my mentalist skills for karma:

HN means Hackernews, and the editor you are looking for is here: http://aloha-editor.org/

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get aloha editor to connect, so I don't know exactly what kind of functionality you're looking for, but if you want a place where you can live-test html, css, javascript, etc. check out [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net). It supports most of the common js frameworks, and has separate input areas for html, css, and javascript, plus an output area that shows the results after you click the Run button.

It allows you to experiment with changing js and styles without needing to have an actual file saved.